# How to create an array with some properties from an inner JSON array in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, typescript

So I have :

```
list = 
    {
      id: 1,
      arr: [
        {index : 1 , description: "lol" , author: "Arthur"},
        {index : 2 , description: "sdadsa" , author: "Bob"},
        {index : 3 , description: "loasd" , author: "Mackenzie"}
      ]
    }
```

and I want to create an array only with description and author property from the arr array.

I tried `var a = {l : list.arr.map(x => {x.description,x.author})}`. But all items from the array are undefined .

Comment: The ```arr``` in your ```list``` is not array, are you sure no typo here?

Comment: Thank you, i edited the question. This is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Are you still have problem? @radurbalau

Comment: No, i figured it out ! Thanks everyone !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another approach would be to use the [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters). This way you can remove the index and keep everything else intact.

```js
var list = {
  id: 1,
  arr: [
    { index: 1, description: "lol", author: "Arthur" },
    { index: 2, description: "sdadsa", author: "Bob" },
    { index: 3, description: "loasd", author: "Mackenzie" },
  ],
};

var a = list.arr.map(({index, ...rest}) => rest);

console.log(a);
```

Comment: Wow, this was great! Amazing thought!

Answer (score 1):

You almost finish, you should define the key in your return object in the map funciton.

```js
var list = {
  id: 1,
  arr: [
    { index: 1, description: "lol", author: "Arthur" },
    { index: 2, description: "sdadsa", author: "Bob" },
    { index: 3, description: "loasd", author: "Mackenzie" },
  ],
};

var a = list.arr.map(x => ({
  description: x.description,
  author: x.author,
}));

console.log(a);
```

Comment: So the mistake was that i didnt had ( ) wrapped to the object when I was returning in map ?

Comment: @radurbalau, yes. Also, you should define the key for the object too.

Answer (score 1):

```js
list = {
  id: 1,
  arr: [{
      index: 1,
      description: "lol",
      author: "Arthur"
    },
    {
      index: 2,
      description: "sdadsa",
      author: "Bob"
    },
    {
      index: 3,
      description: "loasd",
      author: "Mackenzie"
    }
  ]
}

var a = {
  l: list.arr.map(x => ({
    "description": x.description,
    "author": x.author
  }))
}
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

You just forget to define keys in return object.

```js
var list = {
  id: 1,
  arr: [
    { index: 1, description: "lol", author: "Arthur" },
    { index: 2, description: "sdadsa", author: "Bob" },
    { index: 3, description: "loasd", author: "Mackenzie" },
  ],
};

var a = l.arr.map(x => ({
  description: x.description,
  author: x.author,
}));
```